# Django Includes - are they evil?

Tags: django, templates, include, django-templates

A friend and developer I respect recently advised that I avoid using 'Includes' in django templates. The sum of their argument was that includes are 'evil'.

I am having trouble understanding the logic; My novice opinion is that they are a great way to organise chunks of reusable html, and instead of having to edit html in multiple locations I can simply edit it in one when changes must be made.

What do all you geniuses think? Please provide some Pro's and Con's of using includes in Django templates

Comment: if the sum of someone's logic is 'this is evil' then that's not logic!  This is as true of developers as it is for religious people :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a slightly odd opinion. Includes are a perfectly valid part of the template language, have been so since day 1 and have never AFAIK been recommended against or deprecated.

Your friend *might* be trying to say that you should rely more on template inheritance (which is kind of an opposite include). That's true as far as it goes - most of the time it's better to compose your templates of blocks that override or extend ones defined in parent templates. But there's definitely a use-case for includes.

The only other reason he might say that would be because of the added filesystem hit of loading include templates from disk. In which case, he's definitely off the mark - again, the template inheritance model which definitely *is* recommended would have exactly the same hit; and both can be avoided by using the optional caching filesystem loader.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Daniel, includes are perfectly valid for the reasons he mentioned. As such it is difficult to give Pro's and Con's because it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Generally it is best to define common elements of a website inside block tags in a base template and use template inheritance to change out the parts you need on each page. However, if you simply need to reuse a snippet of text in many places, an 'includes' would be perfect.

An important point to note is that includes cannot contain block tags as they are rendered by themselves without any knowledge of the parent page. To better understand this see the note from the [template docs on includes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) or this (non-bug) [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2908). If you find yourself needing this functionality, it may be worth considering if you should instead move the included file into a base template inside a block tag.

Answer (score 2):

He might be saying you'd be better off writing custom tags. So instead of having:

```
{% for post in blog %}
{% include "blog.tmpl" %}
{% endfor %}
```

you should do:

```
{% for post in blog %}
{% formatPost post %}
{% endfor %}
```

The include method relies on the blog posting being in an object called 'post', whereas the custom tag method lets you format anything. For example if you had a page that compared two blog posts, you would send them as as 'post1' and 'post2' in the context and do:

```
   <h1>John Said</h1>
   {% formatPost post1 %}
   <h1>And Fred Said</h1>
   {% formatPost post2 %}
```

Much more reusable. With includes you'd have to rename each of post1 and post2 as 'post' and then include the template...